# Update BSON Document adds a new record C# , then updates new record

Tags: c#, mongodb, document, bson

I am trying to update a bson document based on a filter query however instead of updating the record filtered, it creates a new file and then updates that file from then on. Please can someone help with this? See below code example:

Note - this behaviour doesn't usually occur when not filtering by a nested element.

```
                    //Filter update by user's Id
                    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("UserID", userID);

                    //Filter update by nested bookmark Id to update
                    var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
                    {  new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new 
                       BsonDocument("i.bookmarkID", bookmarkID ))
                    };

                    //variables to update
                    var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
                        .Set("userBookmarks.$[i].Name", viewName)
                        ...
                        ;
                    var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };

                    collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);

                    await App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new homepage());
```

Comment: Yes, just added that tag!